# My array just insert one time into database and ignoring other data

Tags: php, mysqli

I intend to use an array to insert into my database, but only the first data have been inserted into the database and did not insert the other value, below is my code.

```
$orderID=mysqli_insert_id($con);
    $query2="INSERT INTO user_order(orderID, productName,productPrice, Quantity) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
    
    $stmt=mysqli_prepare($con,$query2);
    
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"isii", $orderID, $productName, $productPrice, $Quantity);
    
    foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as  $key => $values)
    {
        
        $productName = $values['Item_Name'];
        $productPrice = $values['Price'];
        $Quantity = $values['Quantity'];
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        
    }
```

Comment: is `orderID` unique-key? shouldn't you increment `$orderID` each loop? or if uses AI just ignore it from your query

Comment: ohhh i delete the line but there an error appear

Comment: what error? `mysqli_insert_id` works on AUTO_INCREMENT so, if that's setup you can omit it in your query

Comment: [How to get the error message in MySQLi?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/1839439)

Comment: What is the return value of `mysqli_stmt_execute()`. Output it with `var_dump()` for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
foreach ($records as $row) {
    $fieldVal1 = mysql_real_escape_string($records[$row][0]);
    $fieldVal2 = mysql_real_escape_string($records[$row][1]);
    $fieldVal3 = mysql_real_escape_string($records[$row][2]);
    $query ="INSERT INTO programming_lang (field1, field2, field3) VALUES ( '". $fieldVal1."','".$fieldVal2."','".$fieldVal3."' )";
    mysqli_query($conn, $query);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are binding the param before they assign.

Try this

```
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as  $key => $values){
        $productName = $values['Item_Name'];
        $productPrice = $values['Price'];
        $Quantity = $values['Quantity'];
        
        $orderID = mysqli_insert_id($con);
        $query2 = "INSERT INTO user_order(orderID, productName,productPrice, Quantity) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
    
        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con,$query2);
    
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"isii", $orderID, $productName, $productPrice, $Quantity);

        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        
    }
```

Comment: hi there I just tried it and still the same

Comment: check your cart, your cart have single or multiple items.